# delete certain lines meeting a criteria except line 1 + sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

This deletes lines matching pattern from filename, with `-i` the output is written to filename

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' filename
```

delete the first 10 lines of a file

```
sed '1,10d'
```

How do I combine the 2 to find the pattern in every line after the first line and if found delete that line? This is my attempt at getting the lines I want to apply my search to(the 2nd line to the last line):

```
tail -n +1 mergedfile.csv | head -n -1
```

How do I add the sed part to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;/pattern/d' file
```

or:

```
sed '1!{/pattern/d}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sed -i '2,${/pattern/d}' filename`

`$`: last line